# Verilog: Can't resolve multiple constant drivers for net

Tags: verilog, hdl, quartus

I am writing a code sung Quartus IDE:
The following is my code:

```
timescale 1s/1ns
module NN50_mk2(In,clk,NN50);
input [15:0] In;
input clk;
reg [15:0] sum;
reg [15:0] temp;
output reg [15:0] NN50;
reg [15:0] fifty=50;
reg [15:0] zero=0;
initial begin
    sum = 0;
    temp = 0;
end
always @(posedge clk) begin
    if(In>fifty) begin
        temp = sum + 1;
        sum = temp;
    end
end
always begin
    #1 NN50 <= temp;
    sum = 0;

end
//always #0.001 sum <= 0;
endmodule
```

So I need the output (NN50) every second and it needs to have the latest 'sum'.

The Errors I get:

```
Error (10028): Can't resolve multiple constant drivers for net "sum[15]" at NN50_mk2.v(22)
Error (10029): Constant driver at NN50_mk2.v(15)
Error (10028): Can't resolve multiple constant drivers for net "sum[14]" at NN50_mk2.v(22)
Error (10028): Can't resolve multiple constant drivers for net "sum[13]" at NN50_mk2.v(22)
Error (10028): Can't resolve multiple constant drivers for net "sum[12]" at NN50_mk2.v(22)
Error (10028): Can't resolve multiple constant drivers for net "sum[11]" at NN50_mk2.v(22)
Error (10028): Can't resolve multiple constant drivers for net "sum[10]" at NN50_mk2.v(22)
Error (10028): Can't resolve multiple constant drivers for net "sum[9]" at NN50_mk2.v(22)
Error (10028): Can't resolve multiple constant drivers for net "sum[8]" at NN50_mk2.v(22)
Error (10028): Can't resolve multiple constant drivers for net "sum[7]" at NN50_mk2.v(22)
Error (10028): Can't resolve multiple constant drivers for net "sum[6]" at NN50_mk2.v(22)
Error (10028): Can't resolve multiple constant drivers for net "sum[5]" at NN50_mk2.v(22)
Error (10028): Can't resolve multiple constant drivers for net "sum[4]" at NN50_mk2.v(22)
Error (10028): Can't resolve multiple constant drivers for net "sum[3]" at NN50_mk2.v(22)
Error (10028): Can't resolve multiple constant drivers for net "sum[2]" at NN50_mk2.v(22)
Error (10028): Can't resolve multiple constant drivers for net "sum[1]" at NN50_mk2.v(22)
Error (10028): Can't resolve multiple constant drivers for net "sum[0]" at NN50_mk2.v(22)
```

Comment: In one always block you say `sum` should change when there's a positive edge of the clock. In another one you say it should just always be 0. Which one do you actually want?

Comment: There are more then 600 posts with the same or nearly the same error message. Did you check any of those?

Answer (score 1):

You set sum in two different simultaneously running processes. So how is it supposed to know which one is supposed to be the right one?

That's what a multi-source driver error is.

Comment: Thank you very much for not only helping with solving the error but also explaining my fundamental mistake which allowed me to rectify a lot of mistakes in my other codes too.

Answer (score 0):

To the above answer i would like to add some more , as you writing the synthesizable code  i would suggest please use Non-Blocking Assignments for the implementation of Sequential logic (Flip-flops,latches) and blocking assignments for the implementation of combinational logic.you can find the references for the suggestions online .from the code you provided  `sum` is a `reg` variable and it is assigned in initial block and 2 always blocks which will be resulted into multi-driver issue when synthesizing the code.All the #delay are only simulation specific ,they can't be synthesizable so even though you write inter-delay or intra delay assignments in the logic-synthesis tool these assignments are ignored.

```
  `timescale 1s/1ns
    module NN50_mk2(
        input      [15:0] In
       ,input             clk
       ,output reg [15:0] NN50
    );

 reg [15:0] sum = 0;

 always @(posedge clk)
     if(In > 50) sum <= #1 sum + 1'b1;
     else        sum <= #1 sum;

 always@*
     NN50 = sum;

endmodule
```